# export same changes commits from git log rev1..rev2 with git diff rev1 failed

Tags: python, git, shell

I have tried write script to analysis the commits diff with two repos: AOSP and QC OSS release, AOSP is the upstream and the QC OSS release have it own local changes.

I use `git log AOSP_TAG..HEAD` in QC OSS repo to list the commit diff. But the changes in result commit list is much more than `git diff AOSP_TAG tag-repo2`.

1. The two repos both have many branches merges/cherry-picks, which mean that they may have same commit with different commit ids in git history
2. Also the QC OSS branch have some commits that are going to its branch first then the upstream, which make things worse(when merge upstream, the local commit is same with upstream,but the commiter is not changed. which make it hard to filt out the same commit)

Is there any way that could export the real commits that same with the git diff ?

P.S. I was thinking of phrase the git diff and using `git log -L line,line:file` to get commit id, but if the change have only deletion then the line search failed(none deleted line in current file)

Comment: A *commit* is a snapshot (plus metadata). To export just the snapshot part of a commit, use `git archive`. To export the actual commit, use `git fetch` or `git push`, which keeps it in the form of a commit. A *diff* is a comparison between two snapshots: this lacks information, which is nice because that makes it smaller, but un-nice because, well, it lacks information. While you can convert *some* commits to diffs, that's not a good idea in general, due to this throwing-away-information concept.

Comment: You're going to need to decide what it is you care about: you clearly *do* want to throw away *some* information (to "analyze" the commits implies reducing them to some more usable form), but it's not clear precisely which commits you want to reduce, nor how you want to reduce them. Figure that out and your problem becomes tractable.

Comment: @torek  The goal for me is to analysis the change list of QC OSS added code upon the AOSP upstream Tag. The git diff loss the commit history for change reason, which makes me try `git log rev1..rev2` way get change list. The change list output from  e.g.`packages/apps/Bluetooth` is 500+ QC changes while the diff change is less than 50 lines. There being commits that commit on both repos. The code in change list is much more than diff output and definitely not only contain patch out of upstream tree I want to track